# Shovel or existing consumers - which has a higher priority in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Let's say I have existing RabbitMQ queue with active consumers.
Now I want to add dynamic shovel.

Will new messages be intercepted by shovel or these active consumers?